# Loads of regex or a char loop for parsing?

Tags: regex, loops

I am creating a code colorizer/lexer for ScintillaNET and I create it using some help from regex:

*Code here for a bit long: http://pastebin.com/9DguegWw*
 - The major problem is in **ColorizeCodeParts**

And I can say that its extremely slow with huge files.

So, Would it be more efferent if done as a normal lexer by a huge char loop ?
Logically, I think each regex loops through the text once so here there is like 10 loops, right ?

I just want to make sure that rewriting it would be worth and that it won't be a waste of time.

The above code is incomplete btw, There is loads more regex for other keywords.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just note that `"/\*\*([\s\S]*?)\*/"` and the others with lazy matching are very inefficient with large texts. You need to unroll those (like [`/\*\*([^*]*(?:\*(?!/)[^*]*)*)\*/`](https://regex101.com/r/zI4mI0/1)).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out but this won't help much really, I've updated the post with the full code and where the real LAG happens.

Comment: There is some work besides regexes in the ColorizeCodeParts. Did you try to run this code with lines #39, #40 removed (containing Editor.StartStyling, Editor.SetStyling), was it slow too?

Comment: Are you asking if the syntax highlighting is doomed to be slow because it uses regexes?  No, it isn't (and your "multiple-loops" theory is incorrect, BTW).  It looks to me like you're doing a lot of unnecessary work.  Why don't you create a recipe as described [here](https://github.com/jacobslusser/ScintillaNET/wiki/Automatic-Syntax-Highlighting) and let the tool do the heavy lifting, the way it's designed to?

Comment: I am trying to create my own custom highlighter instead.